# Search AWS CloudWatch Logs across multiple log groups

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have an application with hundreds of lambdas (in the neighborhood of 1000) and I'd like to be able to collate log data across all of the lambdas.  I understand CloudWatch Log Insights has some capabilities to do this... but I don't think it can on the scale I'm looking at.  I can't reasonably list all log groups--if I could use a wildcard in the log group name that would suffice.

Is there any way to do what I'm needing (efficiently)?  Thanks!